# how to get cells containing keywords separated by a comma to become filter keywords on activating the filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a table of recipes:

```
Dish | Ingredients   | Tools           |
Soup |tomatoes, basil|bowl, fork       |
Pizza|eggs, cheese   |pan, knife, plate|
Pie  |meat, eggs, ham|skillet, knife   |
```

If I activate the filter for column header 'Ingredients', I can only filter whole cell contents:

```
tomatoes, basil
eggs, cheese
meat, eggs, ham
```

However, what I want is to be able to select all individual "tokens" from all cells as in:

```
tomatoes
basil
eggs
cheese
meat
ham
```

Any idea on how to accomplish this? I assume I will need to do some VBA coding to "inject" these tokens into the filter selection list?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible in Excel. You can't modify programmatically the list of filter options. And even being able to select "egg", that would shoes only cells with exact content "egg". However if you open the filter and your anything in the search field, Excel will show all the fields containing that word.

Comment: Sounds more suitable to a database with queries than Excel.  Much pain in excel, easy with queries in a well done database.

Comment: any easy alternatives on solving this problem? there must be someone out there who found a workaround...